# Lambda expression with separate column values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am trying to get a a query to work with user input. I am new to C# and lambdas so sorry for the basic question but I have hit a road block. I am getting an address input from a user in separate fields, 5 separate fields to be exact.

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionHandler.StreetNumber))
            {
                allFeatures = layerFindResults.QueryTools.GetAllFeatures(ReturningColumnsType.AllColumns);
                searchResults = allFeatures.Where(f => f.ColumnValues["STREETNUM"].ToLower().Contains(SessionHandler.StreetNumber.ToLower()).Select(f =>new
                                                     {
                                                         StreetNum = f.ColumnValues["STREETNUM"],
                                                         StreetName = f.ColumnValues["STR_NAME"]
                                                     }).ToList());


            }
```

This works for getting the values in `STREETNUM` but i am wondering if there is a way to get other values that are associated with that column value such as Street name without the user inputting a value for them.

If this is unclear, I am sorry.

Comment: What do you exactly need? You can write a lambda expression mixing && or || operators also.

Comment: Your return type will be a list of all features that match the condition. Have you tried just accessing the properties/items you want according to what is returned?

Comment: i need it to Get the Value in STREETNUM and Values that are in the same object such as street name and street type. so i need to get these values based on the user input in one field.

Comment: So the way i would describe it is if i find one element in StreetNum i want to return all the other column values even if there wasnt an input associated with it

Answer (score 1):

> if there is a way to get other values that are associated

The `Select` is your friend. Select creates a *projection* meaning one is changing from one form of data to another. What you want to do is create a dynamic entity using the `Select` where you extract the *related*/needed data such as here where it returns the city as well:

```
searchResults 
       = allFeatures.Where( ... )
                    .Where( ... )             // Behaves like an `and` between the two where's.
                    .Select(f => new
                    {
                        Street = f.ColumnValues["STREETNUM"],
                        City   = f.ColumnValues["City"]
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Your tactic of deleting your post until you're finished, then undeleting, prevented me from voting up your answer. For the hassle, no vote.

Comment: @ErikE I realized that before the `delete` my answer was *patently* wrong and could incur down votes while I *regrouped* for a updated answer. I will take your comment as a *positive suggestion* which ultimately didn't garner a down vote! :-)

Comment: @OmegaMan This seems like it would work but i am haveing trouble with the syntax i cant get the select to work properly
                                              
                                        
                }

Comment: @user1650547 There is no way for me to divine what your models of the data type looks like...you will have to experiment until you get the dynamic entities values assigned properly from the existing data.

Answer (score -3):

I'm sure there's a way to do this with .Where() and a lambda expression, but IMO you can't beat the LINQ "SQL-like" syntax, i.e.,

```
 searchResults = (from DataType i in allFeatures where f.StreetNum = SessionHandler.StreetNum select i).ToList(); //returns a list of matching objects
```